# Avatars from Facebook do not appear for some users

Tags: bug, profile-picture, images, facebook

Some users have avatars that won't show up, for example, [image]

Consistently across the whole site, for example, in chat oneboxes:

[image]

Inspection of the profile page tells me this is with Facebook avatars.

[image]

My browser refuses to load this <strike>shit</strike> for security reasons:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3MUlphW.png]

I've seen this behaviour for a while now. It might be due the fact that I don't facebook, or perhaps it is in the aftermath of [Heartbleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed)?

This reminds me somewhat of the situation we had back when OSCP verification was introduced (**[Firefox/Opera stops showing Gravatars linked over https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201851/firefox-opera-stops-showing-gravatars-linked-over-https)**), but it doesn't seem to be the same issue, and limited to Facebook's servers.

Comment: Well, its working for most people and I don't think Stack Exchange can control it, being internal Facebook API. Either SE will not let users use their Facebook profile picture as avatar or Facebook will fix their security bug.

Comment: That's more or less why I think it's worth reporting that this has been broken for a while for some users now. It's hurting SE even though the cause might be some external service that SE integrates with/depends on

Comment: Fair enough, I just don't think they can do much at this point. (except maybe contact FB themselves)

Comment: That's a pretty solid thing they can do, and which would surely not help if /I/ did it :)

Comment: I have the same problem and it is extremely annoying. Showing a default avatar when the FB one doesn’t load would be nice.

Comment: When in doubt, use unicorns as default avatars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some user images are not rendering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379661/some-user-images-are-not-rendering)