# Some user images are not rendering

Tags: discussion, profile-page, profile-picture

I noticed some user images are not rendering, like [User 8157105](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157105/alex-hoffmann) (trying to anonymize a bit):

[image]

It looks like the content is being pulled from Facebook. The URL to the image is `https://graph.facebook.com/10155655781319466/picture...`. The problem is, Facebook is blocked due to its poor record on privacy and security (and rightfully so).

If Stack Overflow wishes to allow users off-site resources, then Stack Overflow should fetch the resource for me and forward it to me. Please don't send me a link to a resource from a company known to abuse users and their friends and acquaintances.

---

There's nothing special about my configuration. It blocks trackers and third party cookies:

[image]

Comment: That's actually an interesting question! [GitHub](https://github.com) for instance does something like that. If you embed a picture from another domain in your ReadMe Markdown for example, GitHub fetches that image, and replaces the link to it with `https://camo.githubusercontent.com/<digest>/<image-id>`. They use a project called [Camo](https://github.com/atmos/camo) - more info can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-anonymized-image-urls/). Maybe StackOverflow can implement something like that

Answer (score 0):

If the image is from a blocked site, it won't appear. Simple as that.
You can't really see it if your browser settings block it.

If you want to see the image, the only thing you can really do is unblock Facebook. Otherwise, you can't really get that image. `:(`

Now, Facebook *should* be fine to unblock as long as you block its abilities to set cookies, track your location, etc. and don't log in to Facebook.

<del>If you really want that picture by don't want Facebook on your tail, use a [VPN](https://www.google.com/search?q=vpn).</del> Forget it.

That being said, I am not an expert on that type of stuff, so unblock Facebook at your own risk (the VPN should work, though).

Stack Overflow really shouldn't "fetch the image for you", as it doesn't have to in 99% of cases and it would slow down the site more than it would do good.

*However...*, maybe SO should run all images through imgur. That wouldn't slow down SO, and it would solve the problem.

So Stack Overflow... You know what to do!

But until Stack Overflow (hopefully) does that (they most likely won't do anything, or even see this post), just unblock Facebook. Else, you will just have to suffer from not seeing a random person's meaningless profile picture. (*The horror!*)

Oh, and if you *really* want to see that image...
You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guvlo.jpg).

Comment: Do you understand what a VPN is? A VPN connects two or more private networks. Here, we have the OP and Facebook. The OP doesn’t want to connect to Facebook. How is a VPN supposed to help here?

Comment: @Holger Nope, I have no clue. Like I said I know nothing about this stuff.