# Please don't share my e-mail with Amazon without my express consent

Tags: discussion, survey, legal, privacy

Before the developer survey, I was invited to test it, and promised a $5 gift card from a web shop for taking part.

Recently, I've received this gift card on my personal e-mail. But to my dislike, it was not Stack Overflow that sent me the gift card, but Amazon directly (and in German, a language I don't speak).

Since then, I've had reminders (in German) that I still have this gift card, with no visible way to unsubscribe from these reminders (after running the mail and site through Google Translate).

I'd rather that Amazon didn't have my e-mail at all. I assumed Stack Exchange would obtain gift codes and send them to me, instead of sharing my e-mail with Amazon and letting them contact me.

The damage unfortunately has been done, but please don't do stuff like this again. And if you do, please make sure the user gives their express consent before sharing an e-mail, and name the company you will share the e-mail with.

<sub>I have a dislike for Amazon, the company, because of their work ethics and dubious developments in regards to privacy, but that's beside the point, this shouldn't have happened with any company</sub>

Comment: I've personally found amazon to be notoriously difficult to opt out of marketing for. Be prepared to send a GPDR request because lord knows they don't react to anything else.

Comment: @Magisch I've found companies to react surprisingly fast to a threat of suing them. (I don't know the english term, but in Germany it's an unterlassungklage which roughly translates to lawsuit for omission / stopping of something). At least if you know the relevant key words which google will happily supply.

Comment: @DonQuiKong GDPR is in this case the magic word. Its the law of data protection that any company needs to comply with in the EU. Simply asking them to delete the data shoudl be enough, if they dont, the fines are very very very high (up to 4% of annual global turnover or €20 million – whichever is greater). They generally listen.

Comment: @AnderBiguri uh, well, how many gdpr fines have there been after a complaint from a single customer that their data wasn't deleted? (I don't know for sure, I just haven't heard of any).

Comment: @DonQuiKong To be fair, I haven't heard of any. I have however send quite a lot of emails to companies with GDPR on the text saying that they should delete my data and all of them replied very quickly saying its done. can't prove they have, haven't been contacted again by them though.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I haven't heard of any either, which suggests that it's working.

Comment: Incidentally, the OP's scenario may itself be a violation of GDPR. What's SO's turnover, again? :) (This was a rookie mistake, folks...)

Comment: If you want to find out the exact reason for them doing this, you could send a GPDR Article 15 request for clarification and justification as to the use as your data to SE itself. If there are other technical necessities for this, they might disclose why then

Comment: @Magisch I hope to just get a statement on MSO. While I could make formal requests, SE generally has been very open about their activities, and I'd rather not take any legal steps. The damage unfortunately has been done, and I don't seek any reimbursement or punishment, I just want to make sure this doesn't happen again (and it's also possible I've skipped over some text somewhere stating they were going to do this, if that's the case I'd also like to know it).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I mean, an Article 15 request is a far cry yet from actual legal action, but it'll probably be treated with more urgency then a meta post.

Comment: Comment to acknowledge that we saw this, and to offer our apologies for something that was supposed to be delightful ending up being a bummer. I'm escalating you concerns, and appreciate your patience as I navigate doing that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I just did a GDPR module as part of an induction with a new client. It's either 2% or 4% of turnover depending on the severity of the offence, or 10M /  20M Euros, whichever is the greater.

Comment: Huh I wonder why it was in German. Is that Amazon making that decision based on your name (or I guess based on your email?), or did some of the data sent by SO suggest that Amazon should use German in the email? If so, is SO inferring our preferred language based on our name somewhere along the line and sending this hint to Amazon? I guess from the answer, it's probably just Amazon doing that

Comment: @pushkin I probably had indicated that I'm Dutch so they could send me a card for a relevant web shop in my country. Since Amazon doesn't operate in the Netherlands, I guess they decided Germany was closest (and the German department has been working on (badly) translating their site to Dutch)

Comment: The other failed failsafe here is that an Amazon employee accepted 1,500 email addresses and did not ask for a data protection assurances (i.e. that all folks had given their consent). This is a persistent cultural problem in companies of all sizes - the marketing person who sprays their personal details liberally over the web doesn't care, and thus they can't see how anyone else does either.

Comment: @TimPost I have sympathy for you, but this comment ("something that was supposed to be delightful ended up being a bummer") highlights some glaring problems in a few ways. 1) This is more than a *bummer*, this is a serious data/privacy breach that could cost millions of dollars. 2) The assumption that sacrificing your users' privacy without their consent for what a couple people might think is a convenience is a **big problem** (that many companies face, not just SO). Ideally the entire company from the CEO to the janitor will now complete a mandatory privacy training course.

Comment: 1) Don't give out your e-mail to strangers on the internet. 2) Keep a "spam account" separate from your valuable private e-mail, which you do give out to strangers on the internet. This approach was already obvious back in 1993. Welcome to the internet, it is not a nice place to be.

Comment: @Lundin Don’t blame the victim, please. This is a huge mistake on SO’s side, not on Erik’s side.

Comment: @Lundin: Stack Overflow runs a jobs market, and the most successful software developer community in the history of the web. We should be able to do basic things like trust them with our email addresses.

Comment: **Related:** https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322152/155739 (another recent data breach)

Comment: I'm curious how this relates to the Data Processing part of the TOS: ["Customer acknowledges and expressly agrees that Stack Overflow may engage third party Sub-processors in connection with the provision of the Services."](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/data-processing-agreement-processor) It sounds an awful lot like you may not like it, but you agreed to it. It's also somewhat surprising you're claiming gift card reminders as advertising... it sounds like due diligence on their part to ensure you received the gift.

Comment: @TemporaWolf read a bit further *Stack Overflow will not disclose Customer Data to a third-party except as Customer directs or unless required by law. Should a third-party contact Stack Overflow with a demand for Customer Data, Stack Overflow shall initially redirect such request for Customer Data directly to Customer (including subject access requests pursuant to GDPR so Customer may fulfill its Controller obligations under the GDPR)*

Comment: @Tschallacka IANAL, but I can see a reading where the first is your acknowledgement and express consent to the second. This was SE contracting a third party to perform a service, not an outside request for information from a third party, so the second half of that doesn't apply.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I don't claim the mails are advertisement, nor do I claim this was a ToS or GDPR violation. I'm just saying this was unexpected and unwanted, and I've been unable to opt out of the reminders easily. I'm not that knowledgeable on the legal stuff here, SE might've been well within their rights, it's just been a bad experience for me, and I'm glad they're reviewing their policies on these matters.

Comment: I think your original complaint is valid, and apologies for putting some words in your mouth: others brought up the advertising/privacy stuff. Just responding to the outcry: At this point, it's now a blizzard of GDPR/lawsuit threats from others.

Comment: @Magisch aren't "personally" and "notoriously" kind of opposites? :)

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, that's my take. I think some people got some spam email and apparently according to TylerH it's going to cost millions of dollars. Hopefully they find the marketing person that did this and hang them publicly. 

Comment: @Moritz Naive people get eaten alive on the internet by scammers and greedy companies, it is nothing new. Internet is lawless territory and has been like that for almost 30 years. Is it morally acceptable? Of course not. But that's the state of affairs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just like you'd trust a big Facebook not to give out your private habits to Cambridge Analytica, I bet...

Comment: I think y'all are a bit too quick to call this a GDPR violation. The fact that people weren't informed at the time of disclosure might be a minor one, but the disclosure itself could be explained by legitimate interests in my IANAL opinion. I would leave the threats of lawsuits out of this discussion and focus more on what can be improved in future.

Comment: @Lundin No, I do not trust a behemothic social media corporation like Facebook in the same way that I used to trust a pleasing software development community that was literally created to make the internet a better place.

Comment: @Magisch It's a blatant GDPR violation, and a blatant affront to common sense privacy-friendly data handling, though the threats of lawsuits _are_ a bit much.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't want to open a big GDPR discussion in the comments, but I can't really see the GDPR violation here.  SO could probably even justify it using Art 6. lit. b) GDPR saying they entered a contract of agreement of the minds with you entitling you to recieve that giftcard and that the data transfer / processing was necessary for the expedient fulfillment of the contract on their part. Although this is really the wrong place to be discussing legalities.

Comment: @Magisch You opened up the topic by making a claim, so don't be surprised if you get responses to that claim. :P Certainly the data transfer was far, far, far from "necessary", as covered elsewhere on this page. Whether it's a GDPR violation specifically is really besides the point though.

Comment: @Magisch Stack Overflow is required to disclose all third parties it shares European citizen data with. Can you point me to the list where all companies are listed that Stack Overflow shares data with? Stack Overflow is required to get an OPT-IN for sharing that data. The ideal spot would be in the Privacy Policy, where the companies would be ideally listed, and in general terms be described what is shared for what purpose. No consent, no listing == violation. Then Stack Overflow is required to have with each of the data processors a contract concerning said data. Do they have those?

Comment: I'm sorry I started the GDPR debate and I won't continue it now, ask me in chat to discuss this (if at all)

Comment: What was the wording for the promised gift card?

Comment: @rogerdpack I can only access the mail about it, which says: _As a thank you for helping us test, we will send you a USD$5 gift card_. I think there was a little more info on the survey page, but I can't recall the wording on it nor access it.

Comment: @pushkin As a German citizen residing in Belgium, I got a French gift card so it seems pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @ErikA: Since you mention you're Dutch, it's probably relevant to point out that you have 30 days to [reject StackOverflow's "mandatory" arbitration clause](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28180/how-does-ses-arbitration-clause-hold-up-under-the-gdpr/28183#28183).

Comment: Also see [Some user images are not rendering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379661/608639). Stack Exchange leaves a lot to be desired at times. They act like they have no technological savvy, from unfixed bugs to insecure practices...

Comment: (off) German is wonderful, it is very logical and it is essentially an English with much more information density. Particularly for native English speakers wanting to learn an easy but relative useful foreign language. If you ever will need it, don't miss the option :-) https://german.stackexchange.com is before you. :-)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

We didn't intend to compromise your privacy or subject you to Amazon marketing, and we are sorry.

We expected to get 500 developers to test the 2019 Developer Survey, and instead we got nearly 1,500. Fulfilling the gift cards ended up being a lot more work than we expected for our very small Marketing team.

The most expedient way to deliver the gift cards was to upload a .csv file of email addresses to Amazon. The only data that was supplied to Amazon were the email addresses of 581 users who were receiving the gift card, for the sole purpose of having Amazon contact the recipients with details about how to redeem the Amazon gift card. No other data was supplied, and it only affected the people who received gift cards.

We are reviewing our policies and will be training the product managers, marketing staff and researchers who typically provide compensation to users on how to avoid issues like this in the future.

Again, we apologize for not considering the privacy implications.

Comment: There really should be someone **screaming** stop when even considering something like that. This is a symptom of a deeper issue with privacy and I hope you'll review your processes.

Comment: I've upvoted for your honest answer which described what happened, but I'm not sure how best to convey my dislike for what happened

Comment: I'm disappointed that our privacy was sacrificed for expedience. That's very out of character from what I would have expected.

Comment: Also upvoted answer, not just for honesty, but for detail: exactly what happened.  (Honesty without detail is "incomplete" honesty.)  With detail, users can contribute suggestions how to avoid this in the future.  At some companies they actually have a program that scans outgoing emails and their attachments, and will block saying something like "it appears you may be sending private and/or customer data; this requires manager approval."  A policy/implementation is needed at SE to avoid this in the future.  We learn from our mistakes.  Kudos also to Erik for bringing this to light.

Comment: Also, at many companies (including where i work) all employees that may possibly come in contact with customer or private data (pretty much everyone) must annually take a training course in how to protect customer data, from being inadvertently released or exposed where it should not be seen.  The training raises awareness greatly.  Not a perfect solution (no such thing) but it really does help significantly.

Comment: This should be a serious scandal within the company and I hope you treat it as such. You just broke all data protection laws that I can think of, because you got just x3 the workload you expected to have. I am shocked.

Comment: On top of my last comment, the real question: What are you doing to solve it? I am assuming you have already contacted amazon and made sure the data is not there anymore.

Comment: Did you contact the German office of Amazon, that Erik received the emails in German? I'd have expected from a company which treats any non-English posts on SO as deletable it'd at least be in English.

Comment: To summarise: honest apology is necessary but nowhere near sufficient. You probably need to be contacting Amazon with GDPR (or non-EU equivalent) clout to get everyone opted out. Also, review your hiring policies if this is the sort of nonsense you're getting up to; what scenario on earth means 500 is OK but 1500 is too many? Were you doing this _manually_?

Comment: Can you confirm that no other kind of data was sent to amazon? I'm thinking real names, age, stuff like that.

Comment: Additionally, who exactly is affected by this? Were personal data of users that did not participate in the test disclosed?

Comment: The only data that was supplied to Amazon were the email addresses of those who were receiving the gift card, for the sole purpose of having Amazon contact the recipients with details about how to redeem the Amazon gift card. No other data was supplied, and it only affected the people who received gift cards. We are reviewing our policies and will be training the product managers, marketing staff and researchers who typically provide compensation to users on how to avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Have you made sure Amazon deleted all the emails and asked permission the affected users to share the information again with amazon? If you haven't then you haven't fixed anything, just promised that it wont happen again. This is certainly not enough.

Comment:  I realise that I'm only repeating what everybody else has already said, but although thank you for your clear answer, this is absolutely outrageous! (and, in many places, highly illegal) We're going to need a followup on this to explain what action has been taken to fix the data breach this time, and what action has been taken to stop it from ever happening again.

Comment: kudos for the honesty but, really? Once again, a marketing department is messing  with everyone's privacy for their failure to be able to scale when the workload became too much? I am not surprised.  Having said that, what will be the remedy for this misstep?

Comment: Thanks for the apology but it rings hollow without a clear commitment to fixing the privacy breach.

Comment: @shakyjake I'm guessing they just need some time to review their processes and such things before they can make a clear commitment. I'd expect another post in the near future

Comment: [Tim asked for patience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379804/please-dont-share-my-e-mail-with-amazon-without-my-express-consent#comment667657_379804), I expect a post-mortem later (hopefully this answer is just the beginning).

Comment: For the record, personally I am happy with this answer. Being open about what happened and working on preventing things like this happening again is all I could expect.

Comment: @RobertGrant Even manually, 1500 gift card codes is like a 1 or maybe 2 day task for one person.

Comment: "The only data" other than the fact it's clear to Amazon that all of these emails likely came from highly payed engineers, perfect targets for Amazons aggressive marketing.

Comment: Wow. 1) Create one new SO inbox, `amazon@stackoverflow.com`. 2) Upload a CSV with 1500 labeled email addresses: `amazon+1@stackoverflow.com`, `amazon+2@...`, ... 3) For each incoming email from Amazon, redirect to the real address on the row number matching the label after the plus. 4) Close the new inbox. That's like an hour scripting?

Comment: If any dutch stack overflow members were affected by this this should also be reported as a data breach to the dutch authorities. https://autoriteitpersoonsgegevens.nl/nl/onderwerpen/beveiliging/meldplicht-datalekken this also counts for foreign companies. See page 20 of https://autoriteitpersoonsgegevens.nl/sites/default/files/atoms/files/guidelines_meldplicht_datalekken.pdf Most european countries have reporting requirements similar to this. This quick fix will cost you a LOT of work for handling all privacy databreach requirements of european citizens.

Comment: *"...for the sole purpose of having Amazon contact the recipients with details about how to redeem the Amazon gift card."* Except that wasn't the *sole purpose*; there was also the purpose (intentional or not) of signing people up for endless unstoppable marketing from Amazon. This disclosure is a very good **start** to an answer but there needs to be a lot more about what's being done to rectify the situation with affected users, comply with data & privacy breach laws, & ensure recurrence prevention. SE has been losing a lot of trust lately; I look forward to a longer answer.

Comment: @VinnieJames And recruiting. I hear rumor they have a lot of turnover!

Comment: While appreciating the honest answer, from a quick glance of it I believe at least a couple of privacy laws are breached inside the process. I am not a lawyer though, but I believe it's wise for SE to get some damage control done (collected GDPR request for all 581 users affected for example).

Comment: Re your edit, so although you say the workload increased from the expected 500 to 1500, actually only 581 email addresses were sent? I can't work that one out.

Comment: @bishop Whatyda think this is? Some sort of "Stack Exchange" place where people post questions/answers to scripting problems? If only there were a place for [searching this type of stuff on the inter-webs...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=automated+email)

Comment: You say _We expected to get 500 developers to test ... we got nearly 1,500 ... a lot more work than we expected_, but then you say _581 users who were receiving the gift card_, so was this done with Amazon for **only 581 giftcards**? Meaning 81 more than expected was too much work?

Comment: Conjecture on my part: presumably they expected less than 100% of respondents to qualify for the gift card. Less than 40% did, so if they had had 500 respondents, they would have expected less than 200 gift cards to send.

Comment: @bishop No need to do anything so complex as setting up email redirects.  Just have amazon email an SO employee 1500 codes, and then email one of those codes to each user you want to give the gift to.  Then there's no chance of Amazon sending anything to anyone, as Amazon isn't sending any emails (to customers) at all.

Comment: Email addresses are not private.

Comment: @SeanAnderson They are considered PII, which is private by default (e.g. disclosure is generally forbidden unless it can be justified with a provision in Art 6 GDPR) in the european union. So for the purposes of this discussion, email addresses are private information.

Comment: @SeanAnderson You'll be happy to share yours with everybody here then?

Comment: Even if the email address is not “private” as in it is publicly accessible (e.g. I have email addresses that can be found publicly when looking properly), that does not mean that *giving* them to a third party is an acceptable thing to do.

Comment: What exactly were the terms under which you shared the email addresses with Amazon? According to the SE privacy policy they should meet the requirement " we require that they use your information only for the purpose of providing services to us and that their terms are consistent with this privacy policy.". Is that the case here, or is Amazon free to use the email addresses for their own purposes as well?

Comment: @MadScientist is there a realistic chance that Amazon keeps track of two buckets, "_addresses we may spam_" and "_addresses we may not spam_"?

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes. They need to have a mechanism that tracks user consent for sending mails. Everyone that implements an unsubscribe button has two buckets, and any legit company has to do that by now or face fines.

Comment: @AndrasDeak It doesn't matter. The moment when SE generated the csv containing customer info and send it to amazon without the users' consent, it is a breach of PII. Whether people get spammed or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @tweray I never said that it matters in gauging the current situation. I'd argue that it still matters, because if they _do_ have to have separate buckets _and_ they spam the users, they are independently breaking the law.

Comment: @Servy Considering Amazon's reputation and resources, I could expect that after knowing they are giving 1500 gift codes to SO, they will somehow tag the users of those codes as "developers", "tech" or "higher income than average" for further exploitation of this information (marketing, sales or recommendation purposes) even if the email addresses were not given directly.

Comment: @Adriaan Dutch people aren't the only ones that got foreign Amazon codes. I in Belgium got one from Amazon.fr which I was not able to decipher without translation.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert might be an issue with Amazon in that case. There's no Amazon affiliate in the Netherlands (afaik), which might be the reason Dutch people'd get pointed to the German one. No idea whether gift cards are redeemable on any of the locales, or just the one where it was sent out from. Interesting choice though, because only emailaddresses were shared, so I'd assume you have a local address (as opposed to e.g. Gmail), on which Amazon would base the locale. With a Gmail account only shared, they shouldn't be able to tell you which locale to use

Comment: @Adriaan I used my Gmail. So probably SO send them further information.

Comment: You should have ordered the gift cards in bulk and mailed them out to the recipients

Comment: @DonQuiKong: From more than a year later, I finally have enough perspective to speak. You are right, there usually is. But when you've got one person screaming stop, and another person screaming get the job done somehow, the person screaming stop won't be listened to.

Comment: @LordFarquaad It was a sacrifice S.E. Inc. was willing to make.

Comment: FYI, Email addresses are not private. Every site you create an account with typically adds this as part of their `terms & conditions`, however, the fact that you are a Stack Overflow Community Member, and one who took part in a very specific survey, now lets Amazon know private details. And though, they don't have your name, they may be able to find it from yoru email address, but they don't need it becuase they know enought about you to start targeting you with adds customized for developers. So its not just the email shared, its who they got the email from that did the damage.

Answer (score 131):

I first posted this as a comment, but I feel I it's really important to highlight that this is a **data breach**.

In the European Union data breaches must be reported. Many countries had reporting requirements before GDPR like the Netherlands. That became even more serious as the GDPR was introduced.

If any Dutch Stack Overflow members were affected by this this should also be reported as a data breach to the Dutch authorities. https://autoriteitpersoonsgegevens.nl/nl/onderwerpen/beveiliging/meldplicht-datalekken this also counts for foreign companies. See page 20 of https://autoriteitpersoonsgegevens.nl/sites/default/files/atoms/files/guidelines_meldplicht_datalekken.pdf

I realize that these sites are in Dutch, but that doesn't exclude Stack Overflow from the law or set it free from possible repercussions if it doesn't report this minor data breaches.

Thousands of data breaches are reported and don't get any consequences. This is a minor data breach but it will have to reported and instructions on how to handle it or to inform all affected people have to be followed.

Most European countries have reporting requirements similar to this. This quick fix will cost you a LOT of work for handling all privacy data breach requirements of European citizens. Here is an article that highlights the gist of it https://www.varonis.com/blog/guide-eu-gdpr-breach-notification-rule/

Since this was not the result of a technical error, theft or something out of control, but a **willful** breach of privacy by employees of Stack Overflow, it will probably have to reach out to the European citizens of the 1500 affected people that their data was breached as per requirements.

I **strongly suggest** that the Stack Overflow legal department looks at all the ramifications and requirements that have to be filled per European laws.

Comment: Here is a list of all GDPR Supervisory Authorities of the EU: https://www.varonis.com/blog/gdpr-data-protection-authority-supervisory-listing/

Comment: Considering they shared the [e-mail addresses of more than 100 members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322152) a month ago, and another ~1500 now, I think they (Stack Overflow) should really be investing more time and energy to be GDPR compliant.

Comment: As a European (and Dutch too), GPDR makes me feel like a huge burden. Stack Overflow shouldn't have to be aware that I'm from Europe. Except with such things as GPDR in place they basically have to, if it is true that they have a reporting duty even being a company not housed in Europe.

Comment: @Gimby if this was a mistake, like the cc in the email i would agree. With an intentional breach of privacy I have no feelings of sympathy. Ignorance doesn't qualify as an accident.

Comment: @Gimby Stack Overflow does not "have to be aware that [you're] from Europe". They merely have to follow what are already blindingly obvious privacy best practices, in order not to come a-cropper against the increased enforcement present in European markets. That being said, at least a token familiarity with the markets in which you're doing business probably wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: @g00glen00b Eesh, that passed me by. So this is already a pattern. The dev responsible says they have to "[send the emails] manually from our personal inboxes", e.g. "from GMail". What the actual $£@! is going on at Stack Overflow?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Monetize ALL THE THINGS! aka Spolsky wants a gold-plated bathtub.

Comment: they need to be reported "unless the personal data breach is unlikely to result in a risk to the rights and freedoms of natural persons" - whatever that means

Comment: The problem is that it breached. Amazon started emailing spam. Not only was amazon in violation of several anti spam laws, it was a direct result of stackoverflows actions. If for example good lose an encrypted flashdrive, thats bad but unlikely to pose a risk.

Comment: @Tschallacka I'm not sure what happened entirely but is amazon emailing marketing / spam, or just sending a gift card and a reminder in case you didn't see the first one?

Comment: Any sort of automated email is required to provide unsubscribe options. Also there needs to be a conscious documented opt in to receive automated emails on a certain address. Neither is the case. So its spam by default, no matter how well intentioned. The first email would have been ok ish, borderline, by dutch standards if it would have mentioned that the email adress had been supplied by Stack Overflow. Commercial Email to consumers is troublesome.

Comment: @Tschallacka I'm not sure about EU law, but in the US, only non-transactional commercial email is required to provide unsubscribe options. You don't have to offer a way to unsubscribe from specific transactional events like "you made a purchase" or "here's your gift certificate." See the [FTC CAN-SPAM site](http://bit.ly/2DkCGa0) for more details.

Comment: @Tschallacka Your point about Ignorance is exactly what annoys me most about this whole breach. It's absurd that people don't know what personal information they need to protect in accordance with GDPR if they are going to be working directly with personal information. I'm just a college intern at a company in the western United States, and I never directly touch any client information that I could violate the European privacy laws with, however I still was required to take a 20 minute online course which went over GDPR and company privacy policy. It's SO's fault the employees are ignorant.

Comment: Relevant  [GDPR legislation article 33](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-33-gdpr/): `1. In the case of a personal data breach, the controller shall without undue delay and, where feasible, not later than 72 hours after having become aware of it, notify the personal data breach to the supervisory authority competent in accordance with Article 55, **unless the personal data breach is unlikely to result in a risk to the rights and freedoms of natural persons.** [...]`(emphasis mine).

Comment: @TT I'm sure it could be argued that the right to not be contacted by Amazon without giving prior consent makes the "unless" clause not apply in this case, the breach still needs to be reported.

Comment: I fail to see how this comes close to qualifying as a data breach per GDPR, which specifically defines a data breach as a breach of *security* that led to personal information being revealed accidentally. While that's no excuse for the carelessness here, what happened here was a concious decision - we explicitly and knowingly provided the information. Our security was not breached in any way. The simple fact that it was a poor decision on our part doesn't make it a data breach.

Comment: @DavyM True. IANAL, obviously, and the GDPR legislation is quite a few articles long. In any case, probably a good idea for SO to contact a lawyer specialized in GDPR to give his views.

Comment: @Animuson The security issue is that people aren't trained to protect personal data like they should. No matter how many firewalls you have in place that don't get breached, if you have an employee consciously giving out client personal information, that's your security problem. Would you have considered it a secuirty breach if the person had given out usernames and passwords instead of emails, or still not because the information was explicitly and knowingly provided?

Comment: @DavyM That seems like a far reach. As a counterexample, if a company sold a bunch of personal information to another company, would you also consider that a data breach because their "security" should have prevented the sale? Either way, I'm not gonna argue further. If our attorney thinks this merits reporting then it will be reported. There's not any harm in reporting anyways. So they might just reply back that it doesn't need to be reported, whatever.

Comment: @Animuson Well, yeah, I would think that would be kind of obvious that the company having untrained people in place who think it's okay to sell personal information is absolutely a security breach, and a very major one. Social Engineering attacks are all about getting people to do things they shouldn't, and they're easiest if they people don't understand that they shouldn't do those things. (The 'attack' is Amazon offering to ship the giftcards) But you're right, the attorney can give a real answer that's worth following, I'm just a random voice on the internet, and I'm wrong all the time.

Comment: Per the [privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy), *We may share personal information with third parties who provide services to Stack Overflow, such as payment processors, email delivery services, and advertising providers.* So this is clearly not a data breach (probably not even a GDPR violation, just bad form).

Comment: @Tgr Oh would you look at that... I think you're completely right, this isn't a breach since this behavior is explicitly outlined in the Privacy Policy. What did I say about being wrong all the time? Hehehe... How embarrassing, I definitely didn't read the privacy policy thoroughly.

Comment: @Tgr That is from a section "Information **from** third parties" in the supersection "How **we** collect information about you" the only other mention of payment processors I could find was wrt. Enterprise / Teams billing information.

Comment: @Tgr that same privacy policy says: *Stack Overflow will not disclose Customer Data to a third-party except as Customer directs or unless required by law.* so it seems you should have an explicit consent from the people(a checkbox would suffice) that it is ok for Stack Overflow to share the email with Amazon, causing Amazon to breach email marketing laws as a consequence, since I doubt Stack Overflow has asked for automatic emails permission by third party Amazon. Also,  does Stack Overflow have a written contract as required between processor and processor about the scope and permissions what

Comment: is permissible with the data,**and** does Stack Overflow retrain full control over the data and can instruct Amazon to delete the data? There should be a contract for that.From  lawscot a nice summary of expectations, https://www.lawscot.org.uk/members/business-support/gdpr-general-data-protection-regulation/gdpr-guide/sharing-data-with-third-parties/ and I'm curious if Stack Overflow has fullfilled all those legal requirements.

Comment: *If the data processor wishes to sub-contract any processing, they must obtain written authorisation from the controller. This can be provided in general terms in advance, but the processor must tell the controller the identity of any new sub-processor and any other changes. This allows you to ensure control over the data you hold and to advise the data subjects where their data is and what is happening to it, ensuring fair processing.* I don't see amazon mentioned in the privacy policy. And I doubt there was permission asked at the end of the survey that met above requirements?

Comment: @animuson GDPR isn't limited to breaches caused by third parties breaking into your system. Not at all. Wilfully sharing personal data without good reason and without disclosure is _at the core_ of the regulation. But whether this act meets GDPR legalese specifically is really quite besides the point.

Comment: @Lightness I didn't claim it didn't violate GDPR. That regulation covers a very wide array of different things a company might do. I simply fail to see how this qualifies as one of those specific things - a data breach. Not every single way a company can violate GDPR is a data breach. One of the core words related to data breaches *is* accidentally. There are plenty of things a company can do that aren't accidents.

Comment: @animuson you may be right here. What you guys did is way more serious than a data breach, indeed. So maybe you do not need to report it as such. That said, its been 3 days and still no news about what have you done to fix it, just an "oops". The solution seems easy, just tell Amazon to delete all that info. It starting to seem that you guys do not want to fix it. I wonder how long until someone actually reports SO to whoever enforces GDPR, if it hasn't happened already....

Comment: @animuson Ah, fair enough - I for one have been using that term fairly liberally. Whatever specific term this comes under then; doesn't really matter in context.

Comment: @Magisch yeah the section title is wrong (in general the whole document is pretty confusing, although I'm sure it's harder to write a legible privacy policy than to complain about it). Nevertheless it pretty clearly says the company can subcontract other companies to handle the data. (Not that the privacy policy *has*  to say that, mind you. AFAIK the GDPR does require user consent for data processing, but not specifically for passing the data to another organization for processing, as long as there are suitable controls.)

Comment: @Tschallacka you seem to assume that the user is the data controller and Stackoverflow is the data processor. Actually, the user is the data subject, Stackoverflow is the data controller and Amazon is the data processor. And customers are people who pay Stackoverflow for services, not regular users. It seems like you are just throwing random quotes around without any effort to understand them.

Comment: Also from the definitions sections of GDPR: *‘personal data breach’ means a breach of security leading to the accidental or unlawful destruction, loss, alteration, unauthorised disclosure of, or access to, personal data transmitted, stored or otherwise processed*. Really, if someone tried to give basic programming advice without understanding what words like "loop" or "procedure" mean, that would be considered bad form here, but apparently somehow the same attitude becomes completely acceptable when people are commenting about laws.

Comment: IANAL and all that but my interpretation is that the lawful basis for this processing would be contractual necessity, in order to provide what was promised. So consent wouldn’t be required and it’s not a data breach.

Comment: "Thousands of data breaches are reported and don't get any consequences. This is a minor data breach but it will have to reported and instructions on how to handle it or to inform all affected people have to be followed." Having to spend time and money informing users is most certainly a consequence. I don't want to debate about whether that's good or bad here, but it *is* a consequence.

Comment: @ChrisDiver But *“we will send you a gift card”* does not really imply *“we will contact Amazon to send you a gift card”*.

Comment: @poke it depends how far you want to take it, it doesn’t imply that “doris will create a spreadsheet and email it to dave who will upload to amazon”. Amazon can only use the data for the purposes provided, and can’t process it any further, so no one should be receiving direct marketing from this. It could have been more transparent, but i think the reactions are over the top. Next time SO dont offer gift cards for anyone i suppose.

Comment: @ChrisDiver _“Amazon can only use the data for the purposes provided”_ Legally, yes. But that’s the same legally that should have restricted SO to actually pass the data to them. – I agree that some reactions are over the top, but at the same time this is _not_ just a small mishap. Things like this need to be taken seriously.

Comment: "reach out to the European citizens of the 1500 affected people" - the advice given in this answer is incomplete. The GDPR actually covers non-European citizens as well, when they are in the EU. That shows that once you've gone wrong, you need a proper lawyer to get you back on track.

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323672/misleading-header-information-from-third-parties-in-privacy-policy