# What actions have been taken after the data leak reported on Feb 5 2019?

Tags: support, security, privacy

On Feb 5, 2019, [a data leak was reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379804/please-dont-share-my-e-mail-with-amazon-without-my-express-consent) and a Stack Overflow Product Manager [admitted to causing it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379820/1485872).

We got an "oops, sorry, won't happen again". For some, this is not enough, considering [it's not the first data leak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322152/more-than-15k-bottles-of-viagra-from-kenya-asking-110-people-for-money-seriou) caused by sloppiness on handling personal information.

As I can not see any update than the initial "oops", my question is: what has Stack Overflow done to fix this data leak (*e.g.*, contacting Amazon, contacting the affected users, reporting the data leak to authorities, or anything relevant), and what are the steps that are being taken internally to avoid very serious "oops" situations in the future?

I will use "leak" instead of "breach" to prevent people from focussing on technicalities instead of the actual question.

To be clear, I understand these things take time. I'd be happy to get a "we are looking at this, and we will make a update explaining everything". A promise of a future answer is better than nothing.

Comment: What quiet lives sites without a "meta-site" must live.

Comment: @yivi lives with unreported data breaches, definitely :D What happened was both illegal and caused by laziness, I feel that we deserve a bit more than an "oops".

Comment: I don't think "what happened was illegal" is commonly accepted, nor the fact that this was a data breach.

Comment: @Magisch IANAL, so maybe data breach is not the right word. It being illegal in the EU is quite straightforward, GDPR and such. However I avoided using the illegal word in the question for some reason. If you have a better description than data breach, please fell free to edit the question. ("Enormous fuck-up caused by laziness" sounded worse than "data breach", so I kept the later)

Comment: It's probably necessary to (have) report(ed) the incident (in less than 72 hours after becoming aware of it) if any EU citizens have been affected.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Since you started the GDPR discussion, In my (semi professional, non lawyer) opinion, Stack could reasonably rely on justifying the processing under Art 6. b) "necessary for the completion of a contract between the two parties" wrt. a consideration of the interests. Honestly, not knowing anything else about the process, I wouldn't call this a data breach or illegal, I'd call it unfortunate at best.

Comment: And yes, "necessary" is a malleable term - they could have done it by hand instead, but it's not a "strictly necessary" kind of clause, but a weighing of interests as described in the GDPR preamble / consideration texts to Art 6.

Comment: @Magisch fair, but without all the legalese, it suck that they did this and I am disappointed that it happened, and double disappointed with the response they gave. IANAL nor I want it to be, just an upset user.

Comment: For those terribly interested in the actual directive text, it would seem that the relevant parts of the [GDPR directive EU/2016/679](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679&from=EN) are 85 to 87.

Comment: I dislike legal discussions, as the precise facts of the case are important and the only person qualified to give advice is Stack's own counsel, but I also dislike making assumptions like that this is a) a data breach pursuant to GDPR and b) illegal and asserting those as given.

Comment: Not everything that is legal is a good idea, and not everything that is illegal is a bad one. For me as a user of SO, its not relevant if this is a breach that is illegal and is prohibited by law. Whats relevant for my trust in them is how they perceive this breach, how they respond to it, and how they are going to protect my data in the future. Whats important is if my data is protected (or not). Laws and regulations help with that, but is that really the important point right here?

Comment: @Magisch I don't want to start a discussion on this, but just fyi: "necessary for the completion of a contract between the two parties" is quite clear and doesn't contain any "wrt. a consideration of the interests". At least not from that part you cite. Is it necessary to send the mail-adresses to amazon to complete the contract? No. In my opinion it's reasonable to call this a data breach until someone from SE provides a reasonable explanation why it wouldn't be one. Sure, one could call it "potential data breach" too, but the core point of the question comes across quite well imho.

Comment: @DonQuiKong This is part of the problem with GDPR, what is "necessary" is not clearly defined and highly case dependant. At least in my state in germany, the regulatory agencies have given wide latitude to expediency when it comes to saying something is necessary. Otherwise, under your reasoning, you could argue that using third party payment processors for instance would be unlawful, as businesses could accept payment directly if they wanted and thus the data transfer wouldn't be necessary...

Comment: From the post you linked: "We are reviewing our policies and will be training the product managers, marketing staff and researchers who typically provide compensation to users on how to avoid issues like this in the future." This seems to answer the question of how they'll avoid this happening again in future. It might be a bit vague, but it looks like a typical response from a company for something like this - I doubt you'd get anything more specific.

Comment: That was more of data leak, not breach, but meh... same final results of private information falling into wrong hands, so guess it doesn't really matter or it's called.

Comment: @Polygnome I agree 100%, this is why there is no mention of legal stuff in the question. I just want to know as a user.

Comment: @Dukeling yeah, "oops, won't happen again". I believe that SO tries to keep higher standards than other companies, and this question is a bit to test that. I need to consider how much personal data I want to have in SO if their answer is not going to be more than "oops".

Comment: Considering that it happened still very recently, it might be better to ask when will they communicate about it, because even if they are currently working on it, it might still be too soon to provide a definite answer on what action had been taken and will be take for the future.

Comment: @Walfrat that is a valid answer to this question. *Anythin* but "oops" is a valid answer. To me though, if they haven't done something to fix it already (contact Amazon, the affected users) by now, its too late.

Comment: @AnderBiguri They have not contacted *the affected users*, I know since I was one of them. Now overall I don't care much since "luckily?" Amazon already had all my data including my credit card and home address. However I support this request since the community expect SE to be very professional related to this, the usual *6-8*  is not good enough.

Comment: Half-joking, it's been almost two weeks since that happened.  We all know the pace of Stack Overflow is about six to eight weeks...

Comment: On a very serious note, I genuinely do feel like this is a post which is intended to drag this situation through the mud.  [Again.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379947/1079354)  I **do not** enjoy this, and while I don't deny that it's serious, not being able to be patient and let the process actually take effect is ridiculous to me. The site hasn't had an opportunity to do this again; that is to say, there hasn't been any giveaways or gift cards distributed for anything *new*, so anything they'd tell you *now* would likely be lip service to placate this ire.

Comment: @Makoto I'd honestly be happy with "we are working on it and we promise to update with a real answer". I asked for this in the original post, and because it was ignored I am asking here. I am not in a particular hurry, but as for now there does not seem to be any hint that an update to the users is planned. If it is, I am happy with that

Comment: ...so you're *not* satisfied with Tim Post's answer [in the very question thread I linked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380067/1079354)

Comment: @Skipper for a class action there needs to be damages. Unless Amazon then abuses the email addresses, shares the email addresses and there is a loss from that, as far as I see it, there's no damages. It wouldn't make it past a lawyer.

Comment: This question has an answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379820/3956566). We can't expect a meta post stating: *We have reviewed our policies and are training the product managers, marketing staff and researchers who typically provide compensation to users on how to avoid issues like this in the future.*

Comment: @Makoto I requested the linked answer to be deleted. Re-reading it, it was filled with 2 unsubstantiated points and quite a bit of it was my anger speaking.

Comment: @Makoto The existence of this question, as well as the 86 upvotes it has garnered, would suggest that there are a not insignificant number of users who remain concerned about this issue. While I expect that a fair number of people are just rubbernecking, I also can't believe that everyone involved is simply acting in bad faith.

Comment: @YvetteColomb that is exactly the type of post I was hoping to see. Why can't I expect that? :-(

Comment: @Pureferret to better explain my comment. *It has already been answered* They stated clearly what they intend to implement. I am sure they're implementing it. I don't see why it needs to be restated. That's my opinion only.

Comment: @IanKemp You don't think 86 people in a community of thousands (just Meta here) might rubberneck together? You know how voting culture on meta can be; people see a title and skim the Q and upvote regardless of the fact that this has been addressed thoroughly in the question this was temporarily closed (and rightfully closed) as a dupe of.

Comment: @TylerH So you propose that I am the only person worried about this and the rest of the people are just crusading against SO? Not sure what is harder to believe. "the voting system does not work!" is a weak excuse to not talk about this issue. As I have already explained in few points in here, for some people, a corporation apologizing and promising not doing something bad again is not a real answer. I asked to see if there was something else done, I can see that its not the case. Some people *may* agree with this logic, don't you think so?

Comment: @YvetteColomb my only exposure this this has been through the `featured on meta` card in the top right. I completely missed the separate question that had Tim Post's response in it. Maybe the problem is that this hasn't been widely advertised enough? Do we need a stand alone post? A blog post? I don't know, but I can't imagine I'm the only one out of the loop

Comment: @AnderBiguri No, I propose that your question has already been addressed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379820/2756409) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380067/2756409). Hence it should be closed as a dupe as it already has an answer elsewhere (as the flag dialog describes). By the way, you never responded to [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380312/what-actions-have-been-taken-after-the-data-leak-reported-on-feb-5-2019?noredirect=1#comment671224_380333) - have you actually read those posts?

Comment: @Pureferret there's many meta posts about this. On MSO and MSE. My point is, I'm tired of people posting the same thing over and over to re-hash things in a way that is not constructive. It's not just this incident, it's meta all over and I intend to write a post about it myself.

Comment: @TylerH yes I have read them (and linked them in the question myself), and I was not satisfied with the answer so I posted this question. I have no idea how this fact changes anything or adds to the discussion.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I appreciate this ordeal has been done to death, and I can sympathise that it must be damn tiring having to deal with. I'm not asking for *yet another post*, but an authoritive post. Sounds like you're going to do so, so thanks.

Comment: @AnderBiguri It's relevant because they directly answer your question. Usually (read: when there isn't a Meta Mob running around), this gets questions closed until the OP (you) can explain directly how your questions are different and still unanswered by the *two* posts by *two* separate staff members describing what they're doing in the aftermath. The consideration of bad faith has been levied by some because your description of them is frankly a mischaracterization at best of what was said. That's what led *me* to ask if you'd actually read them (and what Felix' answer addresses).

Comment: @Pureferret there is an authoritative post on this particular question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379804/please-dont-share-my-e-mail-with-amazon-without-my-express-consent/379820#379820 This question is essentially a "are we there yet?" to that, 2 weeks later.

Comment: @TylerH OK, so I was not personally satisfied with those answers and I asked for further information. The answer by the SO team has been that I am hateful, not constructive and that there is nothing else to talk about. I accept that and am not going to push this anywhere further. I am just really surprised that people see this as an attack and not a genuine question.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I suppose I should have said 'authoritive and stand-alone' post. I'm not going to know that question was updated unless I continuous check all the posts about it. That's why I suggested a blog or a separate 'question' post.

Comment: @AnderBiguri No one has said you are hateful. There's a lot of deleted hateful comments under this question and the answer. The issue here is about the email addresses being shared and whether or not that is legal and what is to be done about it. That is the real issue to be addressed, all else is perpetuating a type of drama that needs to stop on here. If the arguments continue I will be locking this post until it can be redirected to the issue at hand and not a production of noise on the site reaching no resolution.

Comment: @YvetteColomb *" I honestly feel like you and other people in comments really loathe and hate me"*-Tim. But regardless, I want to ask a genuine question , do not take it as a smartass reply of mine, I promise its genuine: Yes, this is a "are we there yet?" 2 weeks later. It appears that you do not feel like this is enough time. When is a good time to ask this question? What is the accepted time frame to fix this problem? When can I ask this again (if there hasnt been an update) without the backlash of the people on SO?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I wanted to assess how safe my data is with you. I do not share a lot of info with Facebook, I do not trust them. Should I trust SO? depends how they handle a situation like this, thus I asked. You seem to have added the tag "legal" and assume I am trying to sue you. No, I wanted to know how seriously you take users data and when a massive screw-up happened, how was the company handling it. Without data protection laws, I would have asked the same question.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I honestly do not think that is enough time for a large company to change their policy of interacting with other businesses and re-writing their policy. For them to do it effectively, so as not to have any repeat problems, it will take time. I'm writing a post and will link it here. It will go into more detail about this. I trust SO more than I trust any other organisation. I do not trust any organisation 100%, as they are all fallible. That's my philosophy in life though.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I really appreciate that, honestly.

Comment: @AnderBiguri hang in there. I appreciate it :) I'm trying to write something up to help address many of the peripheral issues that have surfaced here and elsewhere in meta.

Comment: @AnderBiguri posted this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380376/issues-with-how-we-communicate-on-meta-what-do-you-think-about-meta

Comment: My receiving of the $5 was a bit delayed, and occurred after the other post on meta. It was specified there that my details would be shared with PayPal, so it seems some action was taken to make this more consensual.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I'm feeling a *whole* lot of hate here.

I'm not speaking metaphorically. I honestly feel like you and other people in comments *really* loathe and hate me. And not just the company, *me* in particular. That's how I feel, and I can only suggest you think about how vehemently you bang on text boxes going forward; real people with real feelings need to read what you write.

I'll assume the best and just chalk it up to misplaced rage and anger, that's not an environment I thrive in, so this (very) brief answer is going to have to do.

This wasn't a breach. This wasn't a leak. We have a valid business case for sharing your information with a GDPR-compliant third party for fulfillment purposes [and this is very well defined in our privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy). We screwed up *majorly* when our actions didn't coincide with your expectations, but *sharing your email with a third-party to fulfill a gift card, a shirt, a hat, or a sticker* is something that we do ***any time we send you anything.*** And we [owned that screw up and what it means going forward](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379942/why-is-stack-overflows-disclosure-of-email-addresses-to-amazon-a-big-deal/380067#380067).

I don't know what else you expect. How did it happen? Anita explained that. I explained it in more depth, and said, well, we're not going to do that again. It was an over-zealous effort on our part to not inconvenience people, there was nothing treacherous here.

If you have any other questions or concerns, you're welcome to email `legal@stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: For whatever this is worth, know that I at least value your time and energy in responding to these statements.  I can only imagine how frustrating or tense it must be having to deal with this.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you claiming it's was **necessary** to share the emails with Amazon? Because I know full well that gift cards can be purchased and sent to people without Amazon ever receiving the recipient's email. With that regard, your privacy policy is irrelevant when it comes to GDPR.

Comment: Hey Tim, I know there is being a lot of hate towards you, but feel assured that its certainly not coming from my side.  Neither have I hate towards Anita or anyone else in SO.  I saw quite bad comments in the OP, I do not agree with any personal attack on you or anyone there. My data was not breached so I don't have any personal concerns.  I do not think that there was anything treacherous in your actions. Apologies if anything I said *suggested* any of that. It is not how I feel. I am aware that my wording may sound bad now that I reread, it was not my intention to attack anyone personally.

Comment: Unfortunately, while you see this as a personal issue, I see that a big corporation that has a fair amount of my personal data (you guys have my name, job, location, and for giveaway reasons, my home address too), a genuine apology is not good enough for me. When Facebook apologized (multiple times) no one trusted them, they are a big corporation. You guys (as a corporation) are acting similarly. It may be genuine, but in the world we live in, understand that I do not take at face value anything that a corporation says.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Tim's post from the prior question about this covers the concern of precedent a bit. Just to be clear, have you read that response?

Comment: I particularly like this part of your answer: _We screwed up... when our actions didn't coincide with your expectations..._ Sure, SO can help shape expectations, but we all accepted SO's privacy policy when we created an account. The onus is on _the user_ to understand the Ts & Cs. If a user comes away from agreeing with the Ts & Cs thinking that SO can no-way-no-how-ever-ever-never-fornever share any sort of personal information for any reason whatsoever, then they either didn't read it (likely) or should have sought clarification before agreeing. SO can't fix purposeful ignorance.

Comment: [Tangental] Shouldn't the section of the privacy policy *Information from Third Parties* be called *Information Shared withThird Parties* (I assume this is the section you answer  is talking about)? That would make a lot more sense to me since you are the ones sharing it, not receiving it.

Comment: @TimPost You realize that for that privacy policy to hold ground you have to detail with whom data is shared in general terms in your privacy policy for it to be valid? A line like "The minimal required data may be shared with Amazon for promotional purposes" Would have helped. Without the line with which third parties data is shared for which purpose in general terms it doesn't hold. https://www.lawscot.org.uk/members/business-support/gdpr-general-data-protection-regulation/gdpr-guide/sharing-data-with-third-parties/ and I don't feel any hate towards you. I just like things to be done proper.

Comment: @Tschallacka That sounds like a very uk based website. Does it hold any ground on other countries?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier apologies if it seemed I am asking for more, I am not. This is answered as much as they can/want. I however, do not believe it is entitlement to be upset at the way the data has been managed,. I personally do not trust corporations when they promise things, and this may be that I have trust issues, who knows, but its the way I am. And indeed I control the amount of information that I share with them! This is one of the main points of this question. I want to know how much information I am comfortable with sharing, therefore I was looking for an answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Well, you did write "[...] a genuine apology is not good enough for me." I'm not sure in how many other ways than asking for more that can be understood, but am willing to believe you.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier a genuine apology is not enough for me to trust that this wont happen again and that my data will be secure in the future. I hope it sounds less "entitled" this way. That is what I meant, sorry if it sounded differently. There is limited space in this tiny boxes.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32002L0058:en:HTML article 6, will be replaced with more stringent law. and then there is the GDPR  https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/consent/#post-3913  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_and_Electronic_Communications_Directive_2002

Comment: Thanks for the links @Tschallacka. I am skimming through those, and I was already pretty aware of what is being said. I seem to find no correlation whatsoever with my question however. Nothing in there illustrates any kind of legislation these documents and laws hold over other countries, like USA, or any country not in the European union. I might have mispelled "other countries out of Europe", however.

Comment: That's the thing @FélixGagnon-Grenier the USA and other countries may not have adopted these laws, but any website or company servicing people within the borders of Europe will be subject to these laws and corresponding fines. They can still be fined. If they won't pay those fines those companies may lose access to the European market, or they may be forced to pay the fines due to trade treaties. Will be interesting to see when the first fines will be dealt out and not paid what the repercussions will be.

Comment: @Tschallacka Please take this discussion into its own meta post. Your [answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379920/3956566) is food for thought and warrants its own discussion. Have a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323672/misleading-header-information-from-third-parties-in-privacy-policy).

Comment: @YvetteColomb I only posted my comment here to point my point out to Tim Post due to his privacy policy comment. I am no lawyer, I've just had to deal extensively with the GDPR in my role at my company so I have a light grasp on what can and cannot be done. All I have to say is summarized in that answer and the comments below it and I grow tired of it. It is up to Stack Overflow legal to dive into this and to make sure stuff is done proper, which aparently is not the case with a lacking privacy policy. Stack Overflow can do something with it or leave it. Tim Post is officially informed by my

Comment: Comments here and Stack Overflow has no plausible deniability in that regard, not that that matters. I love Tim Post and all the work that he does and I am sure he will do all he can to make sure this headache dossier doesn't turn up on his desk in the future. GDPR is a pain in the behind, and I wish Stack Overflow to be spared of consequences. But it's really up to the legal department to do something. Discussions on Main Meta will only distract and polarize in my opinion. All that needed to be said has been said.

Comment: @Tschallacka sure. I didn't make myself clear. I still think you should take it to MSE. As it's clearly an issue of contention that should be cleared up. Perhaps ask a question? I think it would be helpful. As the discussion about it is hidden behind the answers to these two questions. It would be better to have a discussion specifically about what you're saying.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Feel free to start something up to get something clarified. All they need to do is list parties they share data with and what data in the privacy policy in general words. Not too hard to do. But I don't feel like adding more stress to Tim Post as he currently clearly is under due to these happenings. I'd rather let it rest and give Stack Overflow the room to do the right thing on their own.

Comment: There's nothing personal to you or Anita, maybe the mods are doing quite a good job but I don't see any personal attacks in the 3 related posts. And now a friendly suggestion, is it possible that it's just because [your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380067/2271112) is made inside a less significant post instead of the [origin thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379804/please-dont-share-my-e-mail-with-amazon-without-my-express-consent) that made it less visible, thus caused more questioning? Either way I suggest to calm down and not take it personally.

Comment: Hey Tim, you , of all people, should understand this, posts and comments are for the topic being discussed, not the people. While some comments might have come out as a targeted statement, in good faith, I believe none of them actually is. Let's keep moving forward.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I guess now you can only go ahead and report this as a breach to the authorities in your country. They may then decide if they agree with the assessment that this is no breach or not. Tim: no hate, simply disagreement. And as there is an easy way, at least for us users, to resolve the disagreement, that's what I would do if my data was involved.

Comment: Tim, based on Anita's answer it sounded like the *quickest* solution was used. You've said that you're not going to do that again. I think what people here are wanting is to know 'how' employees will be discouraged from using the 'quickest' solution next time, instead of the one that aligns with our expectations (if reasonable). Are you changing internal policy? Training courses? No hate here, I'm just trying to understand your companies processes.

Comment: Hi Tim. Now that some time has passed and hopefully we both see that this was nothing personal against you or anyone in particular in SO, let me made a small remark of something that has upset me a bit (just a bit, really, I am trying to be constructive): I have still my downvote in your answer because I think that bringing feelings to the discussion is not professional and you only hide the real information that both the question and the answer contain.

Comment: I asked a question because I genuinely wanted to know, not to attack personally anyone. By you assuming that I am, you bring this to a different level of discussion, and now reading the comments everything seems to be about Users vs SO, rather than the original question about handling private data. I am somewhat disenchanted by this approach of solving the problem. I don't want to re-start discussion, just convey my final feelings about all this. I honestly appreciate your answer and your work in general. Thank you very much, and keep maintaining SO good, even if in this case we disagree.

Comment: "We didn't intend...subject you to Amazon marketing."

Yet you did.  It's fair to call that a leak.

Comment: There is a part you could confirm that might help to easy some concerns, if I understand it correctly. My reading of the SE ToS is that when SE passes along this data, the agreement with the relevant third-party is that the data is only used for this specific purpose. So it's not like SE hands out the data and the third party is free to do whatever they want with it.

Comment: As someone who works in a company in a heavily regulated industry, it's not appropriate to say "it won't happen again".  What SPECIFIC steps have you taken to ensure it won't happen again?  This could include an official approvals process concerning data going to the outside as one example.  Don't take this personally.  Getting to a root cause of a problem and finding long term solutions is just a necessary component.

Comment: "This wasn't a breach. This wasn't a leak."
  
Is that the word of SO's legal council?

Comment: @Liam The size of the company and the amount of investment are completely irrelevant. to this discussion, all companies have the same duty of care. As for the personal attacks, I have seen a couple directed at Tim, I don't recall where they were but they do exist. They may have since been removed though.

Comment: BTW anyone in the uk could probably take this matter up with the [ICO](https://ico.org.uk/make-a-complaint/) I presume other bodies exist in most European countries

Comment: @Houseman Not to put words in the mouth of anyone here, but you can expect that when a executive of a company makes a public statement like this, the counsel has probably approved it.

Comment: Mod note: Keep the comments pertinent to the topic discussion and do **not** make personal attacks against anyone, staff or not.

Comment: @Trevor "We didn't [...] subject you to Amazon marketing." ftfy. Removing random words from sentences to make it say whatever ftw.

Comment: Tim, the reason for my downvote on your answer is the same as @AnderBiguri. No where in the question was there any _hint_ at a personal attack; that was something introduced by you on a whim. I would appreciate it if you simply answered the question at hand **and nothing more**. It is _still_ unclear how much of your statement was approved by counsel, and how much of it was written solely by you.

Comment: Tim, I read the question multiple times (and checked its edit history), and I don't see any evidence for "hate" or "rage". (Maybe mild "anger", if that.) Your answer sounds much angrier than the question. It was a perfectly normal, reasonable request: A user is disappointed with SO's reaction so far and asks for more information. I think you misread this quite badly. You should start again with a cool head and then maybe edit or delete your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

> We got an "oops, sorry, won't happen again"

That's an unfair and inaccurate way to present Anita's answer. They answered with transparency, did not try to bail out of responsibility, and exposed what they were doing *as of right now* to remedy to the situation.

Privacy problems are not jokes, and I fully expect them to have a complete post-mortem, evaluation and think about what happened before reporting the steps they are doing. I would totally not trust a company that, after having such a leak, answered the next day with a vague "yeah we understood everything and did this since yesterday".

How much time do you think it takes to review processes, with actual people that know about the topic, and make good decisions? It's been two weeks. If they'd answered the next day, I, for one, would actually be **extremely** suspicious that they'd actually take the matter seriously.

I agree that [[...] the usual 6-8 is not good enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380312/what-actions-have-been-taken-after-the-data-leak-reported-on-feb-5-2019?cb=1#comment671146_380312), but there should be some kind of middle-ground, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I feel its pointless. Aside from the disagreement of the answer they gave, I feel like they should certainly give us an update, at least a "we are working on it". In the original post, this was asked several times (I did ask twice), and they did not give any comment in them actually doing something about it. That makes me extremely suspicious that they are hoping to sweep it under the rug, the same way they did of the previous one (linked in the question). Your hypothesis of them doing something is just that, hypothesis, and therefore it does not answer the question.

Comment: Your hypothesis that they are not, is equally just that, an hypothesis @Ander. That is a pointless statement, we both have hypothesis.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The point is that no hypothesis is a proper answer. OP is not offering their hypothesis as one and their question is an attempt to seek resolution for the hypothesis. I believe that only someone working this issue at stackoverflow is capable of providing a worthy answer here. The rest of us, and our opinions on this matter, will have to wait on the sidelines.

Comment: @JNevill Neither am I offering mine as an answer. I am addressing the way the question is presenting SO's response. This is not main.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier If you are only complaining about "sorry wont happen again", its strange. You may not like the wording, but it is what happened. They answered with transparency "oops", the did not try to bail out of responsibility "sorry", and and exposed what they were doing as of right now to remedy to the situation, "wont happen again". There is really no more information in their answer. "We are reviewing our policies" is a reworded "won't happen again". So you agree with my wording, I'd say. I still see no purpose in this asnwer

Comment: That's ok @Ander. You see no purpose in my answer, I see no purpose in your question. It doesn't mean either of us should delete our post. As for the wording, no, I don't think that the demagogic and charged "oops, sorry, won't happen again" amounts to the same tone as Alita's answer. I don't agree with your wording. Wording matters.

Comment: It is a cultural problem. Stack Overflow is family of sites originating in US, and here the private data culture is still lacking. And most people do not consider your email address such a private data after all. Only in certain heavily regulated industries (like healthcare, for instance) personal data protection is seen at levels on par with European ones.