# Is this Action Required email real or spam?

Tags: support, spam, email

I just received an email with the title "ACTION REQUIRED: $5 gift card" and outlook decided it is spam. All the links in it are to itr-links.stackoverflow.email. I says, i.a. "Instead, we'd like to offer your $5 reward via PayPal. In order to pay you via PayPal, we need to share your email address and name with them, so PayPal can let you know how to claim your reward."

Is it real or spam?

The headers:

```
 Received: from AM0PR10MB2851.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:20b:6e::47)
 by AM6PR10MB2856.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM with HTTPS via
 AM6PR02CA0034.EURPRD02.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Tue, 12 Feb 2019 12:05:04 +0000
Received: from HE1PR1001CA0021.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:3:f7::31)
 by AM0PR10MB2851.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (2603:10a6:208:12f::31) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.1622.16; Tue, 12 Feb
 2019 12:05:03 +0000
Received: from AM5EUR03FT020.eop-EUR03.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:f400:7e08::206) by HE1PR1001CA0021.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:10a6:3:f7::31) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.1622.16 via Frontend
 Transport; Tue, 12 Feb 2019 12:05:03 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 168.245.32.199)
 smtp.mailfrom=em.stackoverflow.email; qsm.co.il; dkim=pass (signature was
 verified) header.d=stackoverflow.email;qsm.co.il; dmarc=pass action=none
 header.from=stackoverflow.email;compauth=pass reason=100
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of em.stackoverflow.email
 designates 168.245.32.199 as permitted sender)
 receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=168.245.32.199;
 helo=o16824532x199.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net;
Received: from o16824532x199.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net (168.245.32.199) by
 AM5EUR03FT020.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.16.116) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.1580.17 via Frontend Transport; Tue, 12 Feb 2019 12:05:02 +0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; 
    d=stackoverflow.email; 
    h=content-type:from:mime-version:reply-to:subject:to; s=s1; 
    bh=3HGm5rLCf26RZG+wifBDWObWfJQ=; b=hAwWAlE3pI6Y425v9RapCtfyTlAri
    7ueS2KRpGaFcPezj2tDYboOrsJ5GWqUfxXCKKeLr735/fJkRWRGcIHtnB1P5tYX4
    zZ+eaZyOaaOQdcv4eC4xdehIAPdTvq3qJwr89xq5bUPm8lxK3g/HX5f0lpEk02mM
    Y0iqoYMvxfaWHM=
Received: by filter1567p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id filter1567p1mdw1-14733-5C62B66C-25
        2019-02-12 12:05:00.478128029 +0000 UTC m=+317119.513163774
Received: from NTg0MTE0MQ (ec2-100-24-43-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com [100.24.43.50])
    by ismtpd0039p1iad1.sendgrid.net (SG) with HTTP id OddmDkyxQ1-ysMOeDGXmWQ
    for <xxxx@qsm.co.il>; Tue, 12 Feb 2019 12:05:00.451 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=4b67c416999e8af1d48f13f77fccc32218d35b0fdb647dabf752c933654d
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 12:05:00 +0000
Feedback-ID: 751566:531499:7014:iterable
From: "Stack Overflow" <support@stackoverflow.email>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Reply-To: support@stackoverflow.email
Subject: ACTION REQUIRED: $5 gift card
To: xxxxx@qsm.co.il
X-Campaign-ID: 531499
X-Message-ID: c45bfa71bbcb44f88236f2aa57fe0f66
Message-ID: <OddmDkyxQ1-ysMOeDGXmWQ@ismtpd0039p1iad1.sendgrid.net>
X-SG-EID: EAdixepjhbofJD8oSRsoUT36nzqLX7VvHAJv2VNUXyTNp3zj+5MVZOL4R87a93akkwlVWzMSNHzL28
 kgw6EJhfvXUjwJm46J+5vLZiMzcwB529dToADFzsL4uXNqfpnEZainaA/6rakGDB8thlnP4h/lAGh6
 wlh+9BZknzMGkskZpkrabk0RQYK8TnJriMPEZ1xF5uAduiy//lsCeet88pVtdboqo1760tx/Bhk7Yg
 U=
X-SG-ID: SmDFk6fVVFXrSNgMN4Q94fBnh+jaBSJJ7mlEyZCKj3e0peFro/qVTU+Muu4PE9Yeom1QW+v8i6sTrE
 PSDVrD8kHGVLOoPoRlQMQx2psiTOXFEdHW3B90ciW+76a5CqoW4oBP4MKqY933bX5FLQpUYMDhvYiP
 xGh1OK+DHzpvPfY=
Return-Path: bounces+5841141-843a-xxxx=qsm.co.il@em.stackoverflow.email
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 12 Feb 2019 12:05:03.2371
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 2:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
 7899d01e-152f-4413-189e-08d690e25202
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 56aed65c-c846-4a90-9a18-d9d2bc8c52ef:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
 CIP:168.245.32.199;IPV:NLI;CTRY:US;EFV:NLI;SFV:SPM;SFS:(10001)(2980300002)(286005)(189003)(199004)(349013);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:9;SRVR:AM0PR10MB2851;H:o16824532x199.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net;FPR:;SPF:Pass;LANG:en;PTR:o16824532x199.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net;MX:1;A:0;CAT:BULK;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM5EUR03FT020;1:BMVExejngdHYzRD/Q4vPogcxAhds0LR/I4KbwdOux3nZ4HRCI/WYYJWJdVcnBejUdvwdhJyF+IzM6ajLUcJxEXxv2+tA5koDceYOc/91nY5xpRjc/FXgKcC8P76wEnEgxxKgBLbQxZ+XNxBMUX1ViL2GLrgvkyEcyCfVeKe5KUA=
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
 AM5EUR03FT020.eop-EUR03.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 7899d01e-152f-4413-189e-08d690e25202
X-Microsoft-Antispam:
 BCL:7;PCL:0;RULEID:(2390118)(7020095)(4652040)(5600110)(711020)(4605077)(4608076)(4709027)(1401299)(8001031)(1421009)(1402068)(71702078);SRVR:AM0PR10MB2851;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM0PR10MB2851;3:gP7QgnxWyUVUy7r1DhQuOuYfxOXOeX1XQAMuZFdK7tL06NFNVRajUbabrJVGT5RIGYgGx+pZk8SVcUCBShNT9HQO0m1Z2G2Lw1DXxSMoTQvn2eZw6LRdRtNDKLslQVQ5S3fOeWiihKAoYniOCZGIqDqj2J7ZOdIKysLsVy5RX19qaZUsNV+t3mphbCVs/iUzRptkEHJlsuaN3UKZONQytEnSbT/dkrPn4dMuwt1KNCsKdmmhe3RS2pLz5Jn3Yw3zQ5YbrxwLJ3QZ1HFm00fSJeZwkY0ebTUipNPy4FMedrYlUmUeoHYSTxmbMptvGLKj6+fP67cl7cXyOOBTF7bISZpGDXo3Vm1h42DxHTFxuQAHIB96T+a3fpJrkzb5Aefd;25:2utylJudvZ1+sfLNVcC0IcFki36Y0hakgX30nuPXnww40xFBBUSecfJIGhWNt+HHZougwZbG78FkFiWhqxeFvSMVtaDUpOF+10zKs4hb3MaJkbuPM64CHKMwwo63nDrO7Enj7EAA1TkKVU58RU1gulFMlKy1oTL+L2Aw5hhYE/PAqlwwoI5jNq/POI7flXiXt7/jTGzXbzjcMVmoVS8rlW5mfEygpOxtmWp8tY/y0ls59usT+M8uHe4EWw4JckWWTAASAWJB1MxZgUb9m/sPbT5GoA+6vDi+t8tSGhl7dAXD95KdZ5wqNMSrA7A3S1wVNAGFrkMsOTMZF5ZNJxoGxg==
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: AM0PR10MB2851:
X-MS-Exchange-PUrlCount: 2
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM0PR10MB2851;31:W7cvDCQIX0/8SaWtoBNpmD0iiQtHwOkhVtLFeFQMfEfgZ8KYoJCDRhOg+QhMqOWJ7OUQ733fEdrMfADbAgcCNY+to5IFt78koFNtTN0Arf7LLRNb1hW/NeMH8xYip9yJr6Cu3z4DmzrGhG0+G/5bPE73a1ZYo21x7HE5Ij3la0TbipXtqjzdm5gCPpd2mwMUAi9cqKJONjqyG9u+8e+mZOorQbsQT/49jYIzH4Bo6DY=;20:Hw1u3SXFjLnfe0oOED4rTtH2cweEXs5HorrJI7CPfzpp0Xkhe9JGTImeR7Yj2ZifeNCj0TnWfVtoFTQTgh4Xh1p2I3Gm8PUR3Xr7eQLvuMQjDlXdisKyZ0n2NxJNQcLlomulgIXH5LSCz9tGw2bshXs4czJfW85Fsf1Wx3wMjgwtow8BO1dRnKlFSfE6Llio+poyazTLv5M3dk3LX8NtPXkRxwTbwve6yeuDu5MTe/XMiB9Er+kCurIaoPeYyk4L;4:pjxiv1ONTuhCSTMS7q3qJfghXX5cLbmMFWVE4vpVDcvlT/wH5Nw7burbv3sDe48Cot8VYhxM2+isk6Nj+pbv0K9jYGf7rndcw97N+HtcSU47Ol28UGO9z3BfQ3315euKrsP/vutXQmxsyo5WNSoCRj7/ocPVu7XAOk1hxSZ+8KgDJdjPoqlVaAGOSyxCoLIDXihU8ARrJqy0dDQDQUg+/YZF4fIfSlMYjPxIXx5y5whdIN7FtXTRxwFvO7ZY24BQ4f/rkJdPlKCV1oOGrBGH9Vjr98Zvuc97XP9T3TQ/9esxkoXIITo4gSBegg88RDRf
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 9
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM0PR10MB2851;23:UMuRcNOX4kMl3yFgktNKIQ+VVYAbfFwXoplpRybxve8p4WrTgW6jaugtuTCmhfgMP69yXELiKKUTE280GQZ35FwtbtkuX7jXCPYb5F6cRJTPYPgfaYyCFsfeGzZTeFpW5RBgaaLOLIY9KxqX+HhMlluwpKgMVNpYdHuDSq5JkEESFxBvIuYm+ppJgIcAgkosnIHDPnRxrV3U8/ru7Jo04IrIpO8//cmySQQYD3kWao1rxTPritpgcVavz+OzFJ0N;6:Zn3sJIZdDPRFa7X8n9qONO5sFsCjpzby41+qHChoe6pJTOkp6vyqhm54gOlD+wqGBiRp43pVbkUPGVvbDzt2tKNBcskPqJw+niGcBtYPu+c8uZgDYl/Yr/5Ml6/2xxhrrKC9UcJW30/IuugY3XqDS3oT50oFnmrn/aqbL074bfpHrwLUsDAMZ9ncq1mYKeYb0COcELxvTalhdPhxsHx3P4IwZ8VEQB2DqMNVuVCBfvH/ifPF/P5VDpFVGNWeIG7JyJ7NcfOsr/DS17nQi5QBR0SA4OIJ9qlttJkxXxmAsRCb3IVLVBSu4clAdmVHdqUgI7mZ7zHYAhoxqv4lIi9laQT0N7C+tgVDL/viijslWu/CiLDaTzCpSAKw1cByqqx6snNhKuBhH3f+kjlQ6dPQG8ktPNspvLqISocvvUzbhFuADcr3nvS88k7wIzeVrWZU+bCdPlzXv3A0eu8YCQVkIw==
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
 1;AM0PR10MB2851;5:pgYmB7+T11lWwFOuiNO7LfecuEPeFSu3YyviPdULbm1rtG0UuK1WTCaCIABdNwPYG4oEX65kuYRinMMgqbljAmIbqmtEH9P/kdIvCnGck1bw6omyWqaX4zlhj8C5h7VpFh6LC2kFRb4/ujAfSfYzzftAgmclDn1bmunLCM2yuloLShP3kIiV31L7CKQsdp8wxFmTFple52NFL3V5QvM9eA==;7:6PE6jU8VBos8+dCvKRFfQ8lDokd16dZIN2+0zl5uKqwt7SrQXmd6juMRh7yGQeFHeO3St4nEbP3AHXvbt6zLjEkq/snL9o1Ul2sAXyXqx0XnGjBFQUceCAc0y1taew7bAT87ciuWxTtLNpj1MmTMqA==
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 12 Feb 2019 12:05:02.4325
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 7899d01e-152f-4413-189e-08d690e25202
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 56aed65c-c846-4a90-9a18-d9d2bc8c52ef
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: AM0PR10MB2851
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:02.3876725
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.1601.011
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;AM6PR10MB2856;9:wFuNUTWpDAwvC30X0b9pOMDTOgvc+NxW0IJZ169kSmsG0WH7dpSyv6vp70PUHcJUAwCJ5XQlbnRqX6S9D5ayBfGiEjKhI4OX2RYJth1p2x7+Mkz+eYjj6oY4ois19JTkyu+5FFmcK791t7qt5eZvOwpy2+HPZ2eRcJyDQOrmVVc=
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    ucf:0;jmr:1;ex:0;auth:0;dest:J;ENG:(20160513016)(750119)(520011016);
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    =?us-ascii?Q?Dumkv7gR1YNVdf8Bfmq1Eh7sdGqRmUI1LOzDDORknel7IQ6Z+NQ7QpRtcxy4?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ajuaY6iLd24QI5LG7qwpIcPKMUQj+9D/ispd15zhzuOmraselzcIxqSc5vy/?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?3Wz+7r5+CLk5TfwdpPECRGZHboUK1k9lBdRj3hKvB5X70ilXYyI7/kcTGvEq?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?8G/SXe+Svg6qSstT6OFyMy/2L0UilyuJCgVXlMmkTMddumZuGD3etYNbXbIJ?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?RpPGUixaod7tuSI+u7yqpNDmGk6KW2/hVqhG+ax8/1rEM29WmL9Nd+hruRSk?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?Ki6f9qpJkf+WvVvRF0EQamwE7GhtgGZAtDVlWuCMQ6PY1Ig6gfMiqswfQxm4?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ZbksgWx5MBMotrf8tTnzykdN5d6/3t4Zqy1JEUNNTb6c/S3ga00nGaCpM5i8?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?/isgPBZ1Bi8/Vag2lf2jsVFFuAg2/jiMlNoDXO4X2INyncwbs1QqJA3jh7RT?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?hAHiYz4tpfVrmXsxkzD2joLkUjQQXkRQnx3vCf/pAx9k8wRTs+gW6FdW/OiM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ZaCUjtkq0ZltwF6UvqMBNGccQYauF8FE1oTYnxbK8Up+R21r4iTQMGTXWNzo?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?kVU8Q8aToxLQCBaHIQMH1FL1bsPAaAeTr8x8W6OZe2HTiC/TyVMCu9ZAqA97?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?xKhlOQPFU46OUuRGseyY5iPWCIz1+Mn4FVKgCfSj655bq8WwHq5mu92x8Mue?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?CCOLiyG66ZVkgxxiJqg3LshGCB8bloYd+Gs0GGOUJpCLPG/mC6eNEsqqwPyo?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?TfJJuDRyI9ZIzri35LcA1LkzBHhGtg+ZFm2pDy3ZNKCMLPJd5ZV4aewXiuCb?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?EzsLtbTLV/+tZDn8hEFTRmFifGGgp2fFAh9ujxl2zQclhktQHXrf0qefPKoT?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?ywl4YFMIUmTBsz8keUpsgSXkO61wi4x8NahV7pIavmR/moEcCqFVbXpsv9oj?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?mIy1/uHXscZYIK8XQPzgVxaI2rY976qA0q3fLSWPNQy8+02iwKR7WpvsZIvt?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?1t6+WhK07u/5l9d44pwVWchUQ9+PmxKPAa//QW+EDbDCvawJ1vjaJaX4eIN0?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?WgM4trCZUFvJFTLnSbdAesIHDH6eCXE/DRnwYufclU7R6/7vpqrRYHHGjKxM?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?XMGpwPRmVKurzFrJ5yX1YUp3gk9ZuUh7u6UM835Ov87k7Ab3AADKrHokfdm4?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?v9DnGYsDP8eYLAW1b3X7pSMuW0XNJk2Ivgy/G3ihpEPdr9xlEtFEZllxLbQC?=
 =?us-ascii?Q?+w9qDUUgt15hVb89LfPRy3HMFh1u1DUV6h7tVJEZ5A=3D=3D?=
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;AM6PR10MB2856;27:CsYRImuGsnaG97bQt8QY6Xc8RRf1p9Q0t68Cow4n/SN9iuNgTwIRdqWN/FG6R3ycQms7eECKqEiOUEcklVrIrN/wM5C5Sqh+B3CzqSy+JIBet0zuOrA1aQsSbQYQf3SEvXFCqbbg/zAX/e7rjNe9DympuM1uVKouj2VuHqpHk7z5ZuLqG2n7CLR+0jw7AxQA4I2r9ulzw1UxopsC5ph9+nNIgl6R9za01E+znLOuM8BsVA0++bEHoRI2niu2SlSl1BdVwS1o0+YwX1sLDKyRUc0xInbh0h2/eFxvwgyUEJ3EwEW8cnUdCyckAFlbSfEajfrKbaBL4FDkdg9GBOEmP8aAIHW49zbscdDNc/3lbG8t9mmcvw4XwVAX6Utt2wFb
```

Comment: May you share the header of the mail redacting your email address to give a better view of the mail. In Outlook, File > Properties > copy past the internet header block in a note pad and censor the information relative to your self.

Comment: Did you do the preview developer survey? See, e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379804/1364007

Comment: I was going to go with "spam", but a whois lookup says stackoverflow.email is registered to Stack Overflow, Inc.  The "ACTION REQUIRED" sure does _sound_ spammy, though.

Comment: And actually nearly everything in the whois is "redacted" except the company name, which makes me wonder if somebody signed up with the right company name and wrong every other bit of information.

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee I did, but the mail did not originate from stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Is this real life? Is this Spamocracy? Caught with no hat on; No escape from low quality; Unicorn eyes; Read the help center and see;
I'm not quite John Skeet, I need no sympathy;
Because I'm easy come, easy go; Upvote high; Downvote low; Anyway the mods blow, doesn't really matter to me, to me.

Comment: Generally, if you see `Authentication-Results: spf=pass`, `Received-SPF: Pass`, and `DKIM-Signature` headers, that's usually and indication of non-spam. See [SPF (Sender Policy Framework)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) for more information. Always best to ask the purported sender too, of course, so good on you.

Comment: @Heretic Today, any mail with a link is suspect. If Microsoft or whoever else is on the route thinks it is spam it is doubly so. Best is not to accepts links unless you are quite certain the mail is genuine.

Comment: Apart from the "alleged" email sender (reminder : it's fakeable), I don't see how this is a duplicate of the currently closed target. This is highly specific, and the spammy smell came mainly from the content.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I assume you meant "Jon Skeet"

Comment: The question is for what do they give you 5 dollars?

Comment: This illustrates why the super-abundance of TLD options is A Bad Thing™!  It's hard to know whether it is kosher or not.

Answer (score 44):

It's real.

You're receiving that because we're not able to provide you with an Amazon GC due to fulfillment issues. Paypal is an option that would work, but we don't want to initiate sending it until we (1) confirm you have an account with that email address and (2) want to receive money from us there.

The `stackoverflow.email` domain is used for most outgoing correspondence that's automated, messages sent through it are considerably stricter than what we send through our primary MX (which is Google) and go through a different exchange.

It's not SPAM, I can confirm, we sent it.

Comment: May I suggest that you post this information somewhere prominent on your site.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne Passed to our marketing / product folks. Sorry if you were startled initially!

Comment: "ACTION REQUIRED" (in capitals, no less) and "gift card" in the same subject line – what was your marketing thinking??

Comment: As Endre said, the title with "ACTION REQUIRED" and "gift card", is typical of spam/phishing emails. Additionally the content, "In order to pay you via PayPal, we need to share your email address and name with them, so PayPal can let you know how to claim your reward.", reads like it was written by a non-native speaker and also looks typical of phishing emails. The marketing/product folks need to improve on this. Although maybe this is deliberate? Is their aim to save money by having recipients delete them as phishing emails?

Comment: Was there a Nigerian prince involved in the marketing department?