# Some Of The Profile Pictures Cannot Display

Tags: bug, profile-picture

I was browsing Stack Overflow but I noticed that the profile pictures cannot be displayed:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: A link to a profile that has this problem would be far more useful than an image

Comment: No, my firewall is disabled.

Comment: There are a lot of examples, I just didn't upload all of them

Comment: No, I don't use it.

Comment: Duplicate? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379661/1364007

Comment: If i have the correct profile, the profile picture is coming directly from i.stack.imgur.com, so it's either firewall, dns, or some combination of the two. Local/regional problem.

Comment: I don't use a custom dns

Comment: I just noticed that when I try to access i.stack.imgur.com it shows me an error page saying 404 Not Found

Comment: I think one of Firefox's tracking protection features blocks images from FaceBook.