# Broken profile Image hosted remotely

Tags: bug, profile-picture

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19482970/797495) was last edited by a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10151315/eli) with a [broken profile image](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-LkfTWrkL1sA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAnnY7qTmBS-nix-r6VNQnBTlpd70Bvm5w/mo/photo.jpg?sz=32) hosted remotely on `googleusercontent.com`. I thought this wasn't possible, because once a new profile image is uploaded, either via direct upload or url, it'd be converted and hosted on a controlled environment.
If this assumption is correct,  why isn't this true here?

[image]

---

**Update:**
The error seems to happen when users login via a google account and it's probably related to google+ shutdown.

[image]

Comment: Related? [Some user images are not rendering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379661/1364007)

Comment: I started to write an answer to this about being able to [provide a URL for a profile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR0y1.png) but didn't want to change my own image, so can't be sure that it won't get uploaded to imgur anyway.

Comment: Probably related to Google+ closure - https://plus.google.com/discover.

Comment: When a user creates a new account through Google/Facebook account, their avatar is fetched directly from there, not (re)uploaded to Stack's Imgur.

Comment: *Duplicated* without a correct answer.

Comment: @CloseVoters this is not a dupe of [Some user images are not rendering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379661/some-user-images-are-not-rendering) which is itself a dupe of [Avatar Facebook](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259904/avatar-facebook). These questions do relate to only some users (me included) which have some **user-settings** that chose not to display these images. **Here we are talking about something broken for everyone**, independently of their browser's settings.

Comment: This seems to happen to new users that register via **google account** and it's certainly not a dupe.